# How to use Select-Object property to expand all the fields in the power shell command

Tags: powershell

```
Get-ChildItem -Path E:\Server_Data\data\2015 -Recurse –File -include "*.txt","*.csv" | Where-Object {$_.Name -like "*transaction*"} | Select-Object -ExpandProperty FullName,LastWriteTime
```

I'm trying to list all files in a folder using `Get-ChildItem` and `Select-Object` property. When I try to use FullName variable to list the fully qualified file name, the file name is getting truncated. Tried to use `-ExpandProperty` to get fully qualified file name. It works for one field but if I try to list both FullName and LastWriteTime, it's not working.

The output from the power shell command will be used in MS SQL Server to load the file names into a specific table.

Please suggest proper syntax for my purpose. Appreciate your help!

Comment: What would you expect it to return? Two individual objects? A concatenated string representation of both?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

```
Get-ChildItem -Path E:\Server_Data\main.sweetbeam.net\data\2015 -Recurse –File -include "*.txt","*.csv" | Where-Object {$_.Name -like "*transaction*"} | Select-Object @{Name="test";Expression={$_.FullName + "`t" + $_.LastWriteTime}} | Select-Object -ExpandProperty test
```

Merged the two fields and used the derived field for my purpose.

Answer (score 4):

Depending on your use case and input, one way to accomplish this is by having two `Select-Object` cmdlets in your pipeline, one to define an array of properties, and one to expand them:

```
PS C:\> $Name,$DisplayName,$Status = Get-Service 
  | Select-Object -First 1 -Property @{
    Name = "MyProperties"
    Expression = { $_.Name,$_.DisplayName,$_.DisplayName }
  } | Select-Object -ExpandProperty MyProperties
```

Comment: Sorry, I didn't get your point. Would you mind updating the syntax I provided above?

Comment: It only works well with one object. What is the significance of the `LastWriteTime` property? Do you need to import the text file contents into tables named `mytable_[somedate]` or similar?

Comment: I have a log of all files loaded into the data warehouse. Hence, I need the file name and the last-modified date of the file to check whether that file is already loaded or not.

Answer (score 3):

If you are **only** going to do this to display on the console, then you can look at using `Format-Table` with the `-Wrap` parameter to display all of the text on the console without truncating the output.

```
Get-ChildItem -Path E:\Server_Data\data\2015 -Recurse –File -include "*.txt","*.csv" |Where-Object {
    $_.Name -like "*transaction*"
} | Format-Table FullName,LastWriteTime -Wrap
```

If you are planning on doing anything else with our output, then you will need to avoid the use of Format-* cmdlets as they add custom formatting to the object and render it effectively useless in the pipeline.

Comment: I will be running this command in MS SQL server and use the output for finding the latest files. Hence Format-Table -wrap option doesn't work as the output is displayed in two lines for each file.

Comment: I would recommend updating your question so that you are stating how you are planning on using the output within SQL.

Comment: Ok Sure. Thanks for your suggestion!!

Answer (score 2):

If you're using the output in another program, you should be converting to CSV, JSON, or XML rather than copying the formatted output. It may also be possible to insert directly into SQL using PowerShell commands.

```
Get-ChildItem -Path E:\Server_Data\data\2015 -Recurse –File -include "*.txt","*.csv" | 
Where-Object {$_.Name -like "*transaction*"} | 
Select-Object FullName,LastWriteTime |
ConvertTo-Csv -NoTypeInformation
```

Other options for the last command are:

- JSON with `ConvertTo-Json`
- XML with `ConvertTo-xml -As String -NoTypeInformation`

Late answer, but this has existed since PowerShell 3.0, so should have been an option.

Answer (score 1):

```bsh
get-eventlog Security `
    -EntryType SuccessAudit `
    -Newest 50 `
    -InstanceId 4624,4634 `
    -ComputerName $env:COMPUTERNAME |
Select-Object -Property *
```

#### OR *(not all fields)*

```bsh
get-eventlog Security `
    -EntryType SuccessAudit `
    -Newest 50 `
    -InstanceId 4624,4634 `
    -ComputerName $env:COMPUTERNAME |
Select-Object -Property TimeGenerated,EventID,Message -PipelineVariable myEvent |
Foreach-Object -Process {
    convertTo-Json -InputObject @{ 
        TimeGenerated = (Get-Date $myEvent.TimeGenerated)
        EventID = $myEvent.EventID
        Message = $myEvent.Message.Substring(0, $myEvent.Message.IndexOf("`r"))
    } -Depth 1
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Hope I'm not late for the game. This one example works for me (Get-Service, more than 1 properties having embedded 'collections' of data)

```
Get-Service |
Select-Object
Name,
Status,
```

... 
and then in the next lines in your script, the next object(s) that you want expanded should be like this
 `@{Name="CustomCol01";Expression={$_.ServicesDependedOn}  },`

`@{Name="CustomCol02";Expression={$_.DependentService}  }`

In the example, the 2 offending objects that I need expanded are *ServicesDependedOn* and *DependentService*

So yeah by custom making new columns it expands whatever Objects for you

Tested works even when redirecting the final output to a csv like this
... `> myfile.csv`