# Powershell convertto-json changing key value

Tags: powershell

Powershell convertto-json changing addressfamily key value

### Without `ConvertTo-Json`:

PowerShell command is `Get-NetIPAddress`

```
IPAddress         : 127.0.0.1
InterfaceIndex    : 1
InterfaceAlias    : Loopback Pseudo-Interface 1
AddressFamily     : IPv4
```

### with `ConvertTo-Json`:

Powershell command is `Get-NetIPAddress | ConvertTo-Json`

```
"PrefixOrigin":  2,
"SuffixOrigin":  2,
"Type":  1,
"Store":  1,
"AddressFamily":  2,
```

AddressFamily value got changed to 2, But I need to keep AddressFamily as IPv4 in json. Not only AdressFamily other parameter values are getting changed. How I can avoid them?

Please help to solve this issue.

Answer (score 2):

Convert to enum values to strings before converting to JSON:

```
Get-NetIPAddress |Select IPAddress,@{Name='AddressFamily';Expression = {$_.AddressFamily -as [string]}} |ConvertTo-Json
```

Do the same for any other enum type value and the JSON will contain the string labels instead of the numerical value

Comment: There are many keys are there like AddressFamily, for all of them do I need to write expression? or is there any generic method?

Comment: @AnilGowda Normal `Get-NetIPAddress` will not show you all of the properties, try using `Get-NetIPAddress | Format-List` to get all of the initial child properties or `Get-NetIPAddress | Get-Member` to see the members and what they contain and `Get-NetIPAddress | Select-Object *` to see the properties and the ones that can be expanded will be like `{value1, value2}`. https://stackoverflow.com/questions/32821165/how-to-use-select-object-property-to-expand-all-the-fields-in-the-power-shell-co will help you

Answer (score 2):

Get-NetIPAddress returns an array of Microsoft.Management.Infrastructure.CimInstance objects which have **LOTS** of (deeply nested) properties.

PowerShell only displays a subset of these properties:

```
'IPAddress','InterfaceIndex','InterfaceAlias','AddressFamily','Type','PrefixLength','PrefixOrigin',
'SuffixOrigin','AddressState','ValidLifetime','PreferredLifetime','SkipAsSource','PolicyStore'
```

Also, PowerShell conveniently converts any enumeration value to its readable **name**.
For instance, if the value for `AddressFamily` equals `2`, PowerShell displays the enum name for that value `IPv4`

I think what you want is to convert the default PowerShell output to a JSON string and to do that you need to get the output, formatted as List in a string. Next split this string on the empty lines and convert it to objects so you can use `ConvertTo-Json`.

Something like this:

```
((Get-NetIPAddress | Format-List | Out-String).Trim() -replace ':', '=' -split '(\r?\n){2,}') | 
Where-Object { ![string]::IsNullOrWhiteSpace($_)} | ConvertFrom-StringData | ConvertTo-Json
```

(Partial) output:

```
    {
        "PreferredLifetime":  "Infinite ([TimeSpan]==MaxValue)",
        "AddressState":  "Preferred",
        "Type":  "Unicast",
        "ValidLifetime":  "Infinite ([TimeSpan]==MaxValue)",
        "PolicyStore":  "ActiveStore",
        "IPAddress":  "127.0.0.1",
        "SkipAsSource":  "False",
        "AddressFamily":  "IPv4",
        "InterfaceIndex":  "1",
        "SuffixOrigin":  "WellKnown",
        "PrefixOrigin":  "WellKnown",
        "PrefixLength":  "8",
        "InterfaceAlias":  "Loopback Pseudo-Interface 1"
    }
```

Comment: Really appreciated, Thank you very much